# How to load the data from a .yml file to database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fixtures

There is a table `questions`, and a data file `questions.yml`. Assume there is no 'Question' model.

'questions.yml' has some recodes dump from the table.

```
---
questions_001:
  title: ttt1
  content: ccc1
questions_002:
  title: ttt2
  content: ccc2
```

I want to load the data from the yml file, insert them to database. But I can't use `rake db:fixtures:load`, because it will treat the content as 'erb' template, which is not want I want

So I want to write another rake task, to load the data manually.

I can read the records by:

```
File.open("#{RAILS_ROOT}/db/fixtures/#{table_name}.yml", 'r') do |file|
   YAML::load(file).each do |record|
      # how to insert the record??
   end
end
```

But I don't know how to insert them.

---

Edit:

I have tried:

```
Class.new(ActiveRecord::Base).create(record)
```

and

```
class Dummy < ActiveRecord::Base {}
Dummy.create(rcord)
```

But nothing inserted to database

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this after loading the date from the yml file to `records`:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Question model just to import the yml file
end
records.each { |record| Question.create(record) }
```

You can simply create a model just for importing. You don't need to create the `app/models/question.rb`. Just write the code above in the script responsible for the importing.

**UPDATE:**

You can use the following function:

```
def create_class(class_name, superclass, &block)
  klass = Class.new superclass, &block
  Object.const_set class_name, klass
end
```

[source](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2390)

```
File.open("#{RAILS_ROOT}/db/fixtures/#{table_name}.yml", 'r') do |file|
  YAML::load(file).each do |record|
    model_name = table_name.singularize.camelize
    create_class(model_name, ActiveRecod::Base) do
      set_table_name table_name.to_sym
    end
    Kernel.const_get(model_name).create(record)
  end
end
```

To use the connection directly you can use the following:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("YOUR SQL CODE")
```

Comment: @Jens Fahnenbruck, thanks, but I assume there is no model 'Question', just the table and the yml file.

Comment: I have this limitation, because there are some tables have no corresponding Models, such as 'questions_tags'

Comment: @Jens, thank you, but sorry, I still need your help. Actually, there is not only the table 'questions', there are some other tables like 'tags/questions_tags/answers/users' and so on, I can't explicitly define model for them. Is there any other common way? For example, only given a connection, table_name, and a hash(record), and insert it to database?

Comment: than create dummy models for all these tables. It should work

Comment: Yes the model name should be the singular and capital version of the table name. I've updated my answer now it should work

Comment: with `create dummy models` I meant to create a correctly named dummy for each table

Comment: @Jens, sorry. Your updated answer works good at most of time, but if there is a join table(no 'id' column), it may fail. For example, my database is postgresql, now I have an exception: PGError: ERROR:  column "id" does not exist
LINE 1: ...01.421875', 26, '2010-05-28 15:58:01.421875') RETURNING "id"

Comment: I want to know, can we just work with 'connection', not depend on the ActiveRecord::Base?

Comment: But we should build the sql manually... Isn't there a method like:
connection.insert('questions', {:title=>'xx', :content=>'xx'})?

Comment: not that I know of. If you want to go through the connection directly you have to build your queries on your own. But why won't you create a Model for each Table, even if it's a very basic model? You can also create models without an id field.

Comment: It seems the best solution, I'm tring now. @Jens, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Got it working thanks to @jigfox 's answer.  Had to modify a bit for the full implementation now with Rails 4.

```rb
table_names = Dir.glob(Rails.root + 'app/models/**.rb').map { |s| Pathname.new(s).basename.to_s.gsub(/\.rb$/,'') }    

table_names.each do |table_name|
  table_name = table_name.pluralize
  path = "#{Rails.root}/db/fixtures/#{table_name}.yml"
  if File.exists?(path)
    File.open(path, 'r') do |file|
      y = YAML::load(file)
      if !y.nil? and y
        y.each do |record|
          model_name = table_name.singularize.camelize
          rec = record[1] 
          rec.tap { |hs| hs.delete("id") }
          Kernel.const_get(model_name).create(rec)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This loads fixtures into the current RAILS_ENV, which, by default, is development.

```
$ rake db:fixtures:load
```